# JQuery .get() call get unexpected data from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to use `.get()` method in JQuery to get data from PHP.

code in JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#choice').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
           $.get('data.php', {
                what: $(this).val()
            }, function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

code in data.php:

```
<?php
if($_GET['what']=='good') {
    echo "<p>hello</p>";
}
?>
```

But the `$('#result').html(data)` doesn't display `"hello"` but

```
"hello" ;} ?>
```

Why is the unexpected `;} and ?>` display in html? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that your above PHP code is as same as that PHP code which you are using..?

Comment: Can you `alert(data);` and paste here what you see?

Comment: `$('#result').load('data.php', {what: $(this).val()})` does the same thing in less lines

Comment: alert(data) prompts window: <?php
if($_GET['what']=='good')
{echo "<p>hello</p>";}
?>

Comment: Also, are you sure PHP is running on the host you're using. You must be accessing the page via a `http://` or `https://` URL, not `file:///`

Comment: PHP source code should not be readable at that level. It seems like your host may not be running PHP.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. I am newbie for PHP and JQuery while using Aptana Studio 3 on Mac OS for development. Should I set up a local server first before using PHP in my JQuery project?

Comment: Your code is working very fine on my side. it only prints "hello" and not "hello";}. I have no idea what mistake you are doing on your side..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need something (a server) handling the PHP code.

If you're using PHP 5.4 or newer (which you should have if you're on Mavericks), you can run the [built-in server](http://php.net/manual/features.commandline.webserver.php), eg

```
cd path/to/project
php -S localhost:8000
```

Then open your browser at `http://localhost:8000/`

Otherwise, you could...

- Setup a [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) LAMP box
- Configure Apache and PHP on your Mac (I've never done this so can't comment)
- Install something like MAMP (not my preference).

Also, as mentioned in my comment, your JavaScript can be simplified to

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#choice').on('change', function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        val && $('#result').load('data.php', {what: val});
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kindly help. After I install XAMPP and setup a running server, it solves the problem.